# How do I actually install and use YouTube Android Player API?

Tags: flutter, dart, libraries, android-youtube-api

I want to make a Flutter app that can play YouTube playlists using the YouTube Android Player API, found here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player

The "Getting started" instructions say:

---

The following documents will help you to set up your development environment and use the YouTube Android Player API:

- The download page provides a link to download the API client library
  and JavaDocs.
- The instructions for registering your application explain how to
  register your app in the Google API Console and to obtain an Android
  API key, which you will need to use the API.
- The setup instructions explain how to set up an API project using
  either Eclipse or IntelliJ.
- The sample applications overview describes the sample applications
  included in the API download.
- The JavaDoc reference provides detailed definitions of the API's
  interfaces, classes, methods, and enums.

---

I've followed every step in those points and links, but I still don't know how to use the provided package in my code! I now have a sample app running on my phone, and apparently using the package... which is cute... but it is in Java, which I don't speak, so it doesn't help me make my own app! Plain English instructions would have been more helpful...

I have tried:

```
import 'com.google.android.youtube.player'
```

and even:

```
import '<path>/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar'
```

but Dart Analysis tells me the URL doesn't exists. And when I try any of the classes that are supposed to be included in the package, I get that it's not defined.

I've tried right-clicking on the `YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar` file and choosing "Add as library", but same result.

So what I normally do is to write something in my pubspec.yaml file, like:

```
dependencies:
  provider: ^4.3.2+3
```

Then I would run `pub get`.

Then I would write `import <package name>` in my code, and now the classes will be ready to use.

What is the correspondence in this case? What am I supposed to do with this package so that I can use the classes in my code? I'm using Android Studio.

Most grateful for guidance!